# I need to write proc which give me report of all my Student, the Male and Female but per different Country?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, report

I have data for my Student in my lookupdata table (Enrolled, Droped Out, Canclled, all with ldTypeID = 129). The rest of my data is stored in vStudent. I need to write proc which will give me a report of all my Student, the Male and Female but per different Country. Where did I go wrong with my code?

Student Status  Total Number    Total # Males   Total # Females

Enrolled
Dropped Out
Cancelled
Graduated

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_ReportPerCountry]
    @CountryID int
    AS
    
    DELETE FROM ReportData WHERE rdTypeID = 2 
    
    INSERT INTO ReportData
        (
        rdSortBy,
        rdTypeID,
        rdName1,
        rdValue1,
    rdValue2,
    rdValue3,
        )
    
    Select 
            0 AS SoryBy,
            2 AS rdTypeID,
            finalStudentStatus,
    sum (case when peFinalStatusID in (303) then 1 else 0 end) as TotalEnrolled,
    sum(case when (peFinalStatusID in (303) and peSexID=7) then 1 else 0 end) as MaleEnrolled,
    sum(case when (peFinalStatusID in (303) and peSexID=8) then 1 else 0 end) as FemaleEnrolled
    from vStudentPerson
    left join (SELECT ldLookupDataID,ldValue FROM LookupData 
                        WHERE ldTypeID = 129 
                        group by ldLookupDataID,ldValue
                        ) sta on peFinalStatusID=sta.ldLookupDataID 
    WHERE peFinalStatusID in (297,298,299,303) and peCountryofResidencyID = 0 or peCountryofResidencyID=@CountryID
```

I find solution, thanks anyway.

```sql
    INSERT INTO ReportData
        (
        rdSortBy,
        rdTypeID,
        rdName1,
        rdValue1, 
        rdValue2,
        rdValue3
        )
    Select 
            0 AS SoryBy,
            1 AS rdTypeID,
            academicYear,
            count (pePersonID) as TotalAwarded,
            sum (case when peSexID = 7 then 1 else 0 end ) as TotalAwardedMale,
            sum (case when peSexID = 8 then 1 else 0 end ) as TotalAwardedFemale
    from vStudentPerson
    left join (SELECT * FROM vStudentPersonScholarship) sch on pePersonID=sch.psPersonID
    where (@CountryID = -1 or peCountryofResidencyID = @CountryID) and psScholarahipRenewalsTypeID=281
    group by sch.academicYear
```

Comment: What is the exact problem that you're facing? on the first look i can see that one problem with your query is that it will give an error saying "Select Statement contains more Items then the Insert list." because it is returning 6 columns. is you select statement returning the correct result? plus a sample of reference data and expected data might be very helpful in this case.

Comment: It need to be afected only 4 rows, but in my case i affected all row that i have depending of my data per country?! I correct the issue with extra columns - sorry about that.

Comment: I doubt it's the cause of your problem, but why are you `LEFT JOIN`ing to a subquery here, instead of just doing a `LEFT JOIN` to the `LookupData` table?